# Selenium with Laravel :: There are no commands defined in the "selenium" namespace

Tags: php, selenium, laravel-5, phpunit, tdd

I installed selenium on Laravel by composer running following command

```
composer require modelizer/selenium "~1.0"
```

And added below listed code block to register Service provider `Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumServiceProvider::class` in app.php

```
$app->singleton(
    Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumServiceProvider::class
);
```

Set configuration to `.env` file.

```
APP_URL="http://example.dev/"
SELENIUM_WIDTH=1024
SELENIUM_HEIGHT=768
```

Cleared laravel configuration cache file.

```
$php artisan config:clear
```

But when I tried to start the selenium server by using command `php artisan selenium:start` I got the following error.

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]

There are no commands defined in the "selenium" namespace.
```

Please help me to get rid from this issue.

Comment: if you type php artisan you will see there is nothing related with selenium. basically you dont have selenium commands yet. I think your installation was failed .

Comment: It was installed successfully with no any error message but there is no `add` command either and it is supposed to come while installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there a need to add

```
$app->singleton(
    Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumServiceProvider::class
);
```

because you already registered `Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumServiceProvider::class` in app.php file

Regarding `php artisan add modelizer/selenium` will work when you add https://github.com/Qafeen/Manager package

Answer (score -1):

Try running below commands:

```
php artisan add modelizer/selenium
php artisan selenium:start
```

Comment: When running `php artisan add modelizer/selenium`, I got error as  `Command "add" is not defined.`